# Object destructuring in typescript and

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking for a way to ready an element from a json object which should be an Array of type category like

```
const { categories: Array<Category> } = response.data
// or
const { categories: Category[] } = response.data
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
const { categories } : { categories: Array<Category> } = response.data
```

Comment: Also maybe better to type `response` or at least data with a full interface if multiple properties. `function someFunction(response: Response & { data: SomeInterface }) {}`. The higher up you type data, the better TS can infer types and catch mistakes.

Comment: If the answer solved the issue for you please mark it as correct to help others :)